# Enter a name based on another cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to populate the consultant name from the MDA tab if their "MDA" number is inputted on the August tab under the MDA1 Column

So if I enter 21761 in MDA1 I want the Consultant Name column on the August tab to populate Abbie Binns

Thanks!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EH-9it2C2IKeF0Hl3gVwjOZ38GmdhOVsapsfhcWFgNI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `XLOOKUP()` function.

```
=XLOOKUP(O5,MDA!B:B,MDA!C:C)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! And what if I wanted to do it the other way around so if I typed their name "Abbie Binns" in the consultant column for it to populate the MDA? I tried amending your formula from O5 to N5 but it didn't work :(

Comment: @Beth Glad to know! Please accept the answer (tick mark it) to treat the question as solved. To do that you just need to switch parameters. Give a try to `=XLOOKUP(O5,MDA!C:C,MDA!B:B)`

Comment: When I switch and do "=XLOOKUP(O5,MDA!C:C,MDA!B:B)" it comes up with: Circular dependency detected. To resolve with iterative calculation, see File > Settings. - I then went to settings and amended this, it now says "Did not find value '0' in XLOOKUP evaluation."

Comment: Sorry Harun, can you please help?

Comment: @Beth Yes, I will look again when I am free and will sit Infront of computer.

Comment: Thank you, I still cannot figure this out :(

Answer (score 0):

```
=VLOOKUP(O5,MDA!B:C,2,0)
```

enter this formula in cell N
and I would remove those drop down menus

[image]